# Eigenvector of complex orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Let $g$ be a complex orthogonal matrix,i.e.$g \in M(n,C)$ and $g^tg=I_n$.

It is known that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $g$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$ and $|\lambda|≠1$,we must have $v^tv＝0$ and there must exist $w≠0$ such that $gw＝\lambda^{-1}w$.

I am interested in the case satisfying that $v≠0$ is an eigenvector of $g$ with eigenvalue $1$ and $v^tv=0$. Is there another eigenvector $w≠v,w≠0$, such that $gw=w$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by the answers to your other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4660182), there exists a complex orthogonal matrix $g$ that has at least two linearly independent eigenvectors $v$ and $w$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, such that $v^tv=w^tw=0$.

Yet, there also exists a complex orthogonal matrix $g$ that has only one eigenvector $v$ (up to scaling) corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ such that $v^tv=0$. Here is a concrete example. Let $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,
$$
X=\pmatrix{r&0&\frac{9}{8}r\\ 0&i&-\frac12i\\ ir&0&-\frac78ir}
\quad\text{and}\quad
J=\pmatrix{1&1\\ &1&1\\ &&1}.
$$
Then
$$
X^tX
=\pmatrix{r&0&ir\\ 0&i&0\\ \frac{9}{8}r&-\frac{1}{2}i&-\frac{7}{8}ir}
\pmatrix{r&0&\frac{9}{8}r\\ 0&i&-\frac12i\\ ir&0&-\frac78ir}
=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&-1&\frac12\\ 1&\frac12&0}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
J^t(X^tX)J
&=\pmatrix{1\\ 1&1\\ &1&1}
\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&-1&\frac12\\ 1&\frac12&0}
\pmatrix{1&1\\ &1&1\\ &&1}\\
&=\pmatrix{1\\ 1&1\\ &1&1}
\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&-1&-\frac12\\ 1&\frac32&\frac12}=X^tX.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore $I=(X^t)^{-1}J^t(X^tX)JX^{-1}=(XJX^{-1})^t(XJX^{-1})$. That is, $g= XJX^{-1}$ is complex orthogonal. As the Jordan form of $g$ is $J$, its eigenspace for the eigenvalue $1$ is one-dimensional. This eigenspace is spanned by the first column of $X$, which is $v=r(1,0,i)^t$. Therefore $v^tv=0$.

If you want the numeric value of $g$, it is
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{5}{4}&-ir&\frac{i}{4}\\
ir&1&-r\\
\frac{i}{4}&r&\frac{3}{4}}.
$$

I have followed chapter 4 of Olga Ruff’s master thesis [*The Jordan Canonical Forms of orthogonal and skew-symmetric matrices: characterization and examples*](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=868775f3939ddae1b2092948cbc06c6851b9caee) (whose results, albeit not entirely original, are handy) to construct this $g$.