# A problem of eigenvectors of 3×3 complex orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Let $v$,$w$ be two complex vectors in $C^3$ satisfying that $v^tv=w^tw=0$ and $v$,$w$ are linearly independent.

I want to know whether there always exists a 3×3 complex orthogonal matrix $g≠I_3,-I_3$ $g^tg=I_3$ such that both $v$ and $w$ are eigenvector of $g$？

Comment: Pure dot product $u^tv$ isn't usual in this context ; why not **hermitian** dot product $\overline{u}^tv$ ?

Comment: It is difficult for me just because it is very unusual.And difficult to compute.

Comment: Another reason may be that orthogonal group is an algebraic group but unitary group is not.

Comment: Please confirm that your definition of " g is orthogonal" is $g^tg=I_3$.

Comment: @Jean Marie As odd as the conditions $\ v^tv=w^tw=0\ $ appear to be, the conditions $\ \bar{v}^tv=\bar{w}^tw=0\ $ would imply $\ v=w=0\ $, and hence be inconsistent with the requirement that $\ v\ $ and $\ w\ $ be linearly independent.

Comment: @lonza leggueza hi,leggiera!You seem to delete your answer just now.Is there any problem?I check part of your answer and wonder that whether $v^tv$ degenerated on any 2-dim subspace or not.

Comment: @wsh In my answer I had assumed that by "orthogonal" you meant "unitary". Calling a matrix "[orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)" is usually taken to imply that the matrix has real entries, and the generalisation of that   concept  to complex matrices is a *unitary* matrix, which satisfies $\ \bar{g}^tg=I\ $, rather than $\ g^tg=I\ $. As you've now specified that the latter condition is what you mean by orthogonal, my proposed answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @lonza leggiera thank you after all! Could you think more about it?Or you can give a counterexample

Comment: @wsh I have now updated my answer to use the definition of "orthogonal" you specify in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,under the conditions stated,
$$
g=I_3-\frac{2}{w^tv}\big(wv^t+vw^t\big)
$$
is such an "orthogonal" matrix.  The stated conditions guarantee that $\ w^tv\ne0\ $.
\begin{align}
gv&=v-\frac{2}{w^tv}\big(v^tvw+w^tvv\big)\\
&=-v\ ,\ \text{ and}\\
gw&=w-\frac{2}{w^tv}\big(v^tww+w^twv\big)\\
&=-w\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ v\ $ and $\ w\ $ are eigenvectors of $\ g\ $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\ {-}1\ $.

Also,  $\ g\ $ is symmetric, so
\begin{align}
g^tg&=g^2\\
    &=I_3^2-\frac{4}{w^tv}\big(wv^t+vw^t\big)+\frac{4}{\big(w^tv\big)^2}\big(wv^t+vw^t\big)^2\\
&=I_3-\frac{4}{w^tv}\big(wv^t+vw^t\big)+\frac{4}{\big(w^tv\big)^2}\big(v^twwv^t+w^tvvw^t\big)\\
&=I_3-\frac{4}{w^tv}\big(wv^t+vw^t\big)+\frac{4w^tv}{\big(w^tv\big)^2}\big(wv^t+vw^t\big)\\
&=I_3\ .
\end{align}

Comment: thank you very much！I understand your idea and overcome some details such as $w^tv≠0$ and $g≠+I_3,-I_3$.In conclusion,I seems totally solve this problem owning to your great help!

Comment: @wsh There's still one wrinkle left to deal with.  The solution only works when $\ w^tv\ne0\ $.  When writing out the answer, I thought it would be easy to show that this followed from the other specified conditions. However, I haven't yet been able to prove it, so it might not always be true.

Comment: @user1551 It seems that $w^tv=0$ cannot happen.Let $Q=(v,w,w)$, then $rank(Q)=2$ for $v,w$ linearly independent.But $Q^tQ=0$ $0=rank(Q^tQ)≥2rank(Q)-3=1$   contradiction!

Comment: @user1551 Yes,the above just shows $v,w$ cannot be both linearly independent and orthogonal under transport.And I've assumed the first held.

Comment: @user1551 for $rank(AB)+3≥rank(A)+rank(B)$

Comment: @wsh Oh, you mean Sylvester's rank inequality. Yes, you are right.

Comment: @user1551 ok,thank you

Comment: @wsh Yes, I think I've finally managed to find a proof   that $\ v^tv=$$\,w^tw=$$\,w^tv=$$\,0\ $ implies that $\ w\ $ and $\ v\ $ are linearly dependent, but it's somewhat more laborious than your above argument.  So unless you really want to see all the gory details I won't bother adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $g$ always exists. At the end of this answer we will obtain the general form of $g$.

By a result from Horn and Merino, the Jordan form of a complex orthogonal matrix must be a direct sum of matrices of the following types:

- $J_k(\lambda)\oplus J_k(\lambda^{-1})$ for any $k$ and for some $\lambda\ne0$,
- $J_k(1)$ for any odd $k$,
- $J_k(-1)$ for any odd $k$.

Since $g$ has two linearly independent eigenvectors $v$ and $w$, its Jordan form is not a single Jordan block. As $g\ne\pm I$ and $\det g=\pm1$, it follows from the above result that $g$ is diagonalisable and its Jordan form is either $\operatorname{diag}(\pm1,\pm1,\mp1)$ or $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda,\frac{1}{\lambda},\pm1)$. So, by considering $-g$ instead of $g$ if necessary, we may assume that its spectrum is $\{\lambda,\frac{1}{\lambda},1\}$ for some $\lambda\notin\{0,1\}$.

Let $\{v,w,x\}$ be an eigenbasis of $g$. Then $g=PDP^{-1}$ where $P=\pmatrix{v&w&x}$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. So, $g^tg=I$ if and only if $DP^tPD=P^tP$. Now there are three possibilities:

1. If $\lambda\ne-1$, then the condition $DP^tPD=P^tP$ implies that $x^tv=x^tw=0$.
2. If $\lambda=-1$ and $gx=x$, the condition $DP^tPD=P^tP$ also implies that $x^tv=x^tw=0$.
3. If $\lambda=-1$ but $gv=v,\,gx=x$ and $gw=-w$, then $D=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,-1)$ and hence the condition
   $$
   \pmatrix{0&-v^tw&v^tx\\ -w^tv&0&-w^tx\\ x^tv&-x^tw&x^tx}
   = DP^tPD=P^tP=
   \pmatrix{0&v^tw&v^tx\\ w^tv&0&w^tx\\ x^tv&x^tw&x^tx}
   $$
   implies that
   $$
   P^tP=
   \pmatrix{0&0&v^tx\\ 0&0&0\\ x^tv&0&x^tx},
   $$
   but this is impossible because $P^tP$ is nonsingular.

Hence we must have $x^tv=x^tw=0$. Note that the vector $x$ always exists: as $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, $X=\{x:x^tv=x^tw=0\}$ is one-dimensional. Hence $v^tw$ is necessarily nonzero (or else both $v$ and $w$ will lie inside $X$) and if $x$ spans $X$, then $\{v,w,x\}$ must be linearly independent. Moreover, as $\pmatrix{v&w&x}$ is nonsingular, $x^t\pmatrix{v&w&x}= \pmatrix{0&0&x^tx} $ is nonzero. Hence $x^tx\ne0$.

We may also give an explicit expression of $x$. Since $u\cdot(v\times w)=\det\pmatrix{u&v&w}$ for every vector $u$ (where the dot and cross products are calculated using the same formulae as in the real case), $v\times w$ must be a nonzero scalar multiple $x$ (otherwise we may put $u=x$ to arrive at a contradiction). Therefore $x=v\times w$ (up to scaling).

Anyway, from our previous discussion, we conclude that the general solution is given by:
$$
g=\pm P\pmatrix{\lambda\\ &\frac{1}{\lambda}\\ &&1}P^{-1}
$$
where $\lambda\ne0,1$. The answer by lonza leggiera is the case where $g=P\operatorname{diag}(-1,-1,1)P^{-1}$.

Comment: I think you are right!thank you!